# Can't able to get description of SNMP v2 traps

Tags: linux, snmp, oid, snmp-trap

I am sending SNMP v2 trap with OID specific to some organisation but I can't find description in Ireasoning trap watcher,also I have captured snmp trap in wireshark in that I'm able to find description of trap,so what is minimal requirement for sending Organisation specific snmp v2 traps?

I have tried different snmp trap wathcher and getting traps but not able to find any description.

Comment: Per @Lex-Li's answer, the reason you're missing the description of the traps is because the relevant MIB document is not loaded. You will need to hunt down the MIB document. The most common MIBS are shipped with the trap watcher, but you will have to load them (some only support loading a few at a time and don't load any by default). If the OID is some company, then for the most part you will need to obtain the MIB from either their publically available documents, or their software, or from customer support.

Comment: OK,I have MIB so can you please suggest best SNMP trap watcher application?

Comment: You're asking a personal opinion question.  I use `snmpd`. It works for what I want - produce logs that can be parsed - my primary use of a listener is for integration testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking two requirements are there for a trap listener application to correctly report the information,

- The TRAP v2 message is in proper format (http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion2SNMPv2MessageFormats-5.htm).
- The listener app has the corresponding MIB documents loaded.

Thus, have you reviewed both?

Comment: Thanks for help,I forgot to load MIB..

Comment: Can you suggest me best Trap listener for sending snmp v2 traps with OIDs???

Comment: @RiteshPrajapati, why do you want the best when in fact most of them are feature complete and of production quality? Change your mind please.